# rules engine plugin issue in CDF

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion

In CDF, rules engine is a transform available. However, when its used in a pipeline with below syntax, get an error

```
rulebook "Titanic  Normalization" {
  version 1

  meta {
    description "This rule book applies transformation on the titanic feed."
    source "titanic-rules.xslx"
    user "joltie"
  }

  rule "csv-to-fields" {
    description "trial"
    when(present(body)) then {
      parse-as-csv body ',' false;
      drop body;
      set columns F1,F2,F3;
      cleanse-column-names;
    }
  }
}
```

So Do we need to explicitly install DRE to make this work? do we need source excel mentioned in meta section?

Comment: adiideas: What is the version of CDF are you using? Can you talk a little bit more on what you are trying to do and your usecase?

Comment: Hey Ajai, its 6.1.3. Usecase: If I have 200 odd elements to transform with say 5-10 rules, then  rules engine is way more convenient to implement than Wrangler. Wrangler is field driven whereas Rules engine is rule driven. So you code 5-10 rules and add relevant fields in respective rules and you are done. Thats my understanding after reading documentation.

Comment: adiideas: Rules engine is not supported in CDF yet.